# Deleting a folder under my artifact in artifactory

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, curl, artifactory

I have a folder structure as Backup/Date/hostname/*zip.
I want to delete the folder date which has 7 days prior date than current. 
I am using below command:

```
curl -k -u user:pass -X DELETE https://artifactory.test.com/artifactory/Backup/$Date.
```

But it is deleting the entire `Backup` artifact from `artifactory`.

It is to be done by [curl](/questions/tagged/curl), or any other means, but not through **jfrog cli** because I have to run this in `jenkins`.

How can this be resolved?

Comment: You mentioned that you don't want to use JFrog CLI, because you're running this in Jenkins. Why can't you run JFrog CLI from Jenkins? You can easily install JFrog CLI using a curl command, as shown in the Get JFrog CLI page online.

Comment: You could make use of the pattern given in jfrog's github repo to delete a particular 
file or folder from artifactory. [Artifactory-Cleanup.sh](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jfrog/artifactory-scripts/master/Artifactory-Cleanup.sh)

Comment: The command you are using look OK. Please make sure that the $Date variable has a value when running the command

Comment: Hi Dror, It is taking current date, how can i give date which is 7 less than current date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your date format is `ddmmyyyy`, try

```
DATE=$(date --date="7 days ago" +%d%m%Y)
curl -k -u user:pass -X DELETE https://artifactory.test.com/artifactory/Backup/${DATE}
```

Edit: If from Jenkins, do as below.

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '<your-credsID>', passwordVariable: 'pass', usernameVariable: 'user')]) {
  sh '''
  DATE=$(date --date="7 days ago" +%d%m%Y)
  curl -k -u $user:$pass -X DELETE https://artifactory.test.com/artifactory/Backup/${DATE}
  '''  
}
```

Comment: I am running this command from jenkins, but it is throwing some error

Comment: @SubhamKumar Please find my Edit.